# How create regexp for reapeted pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

In string available only 3 parameters :
C1 - number is only 0 or 1
R1 - number is only 0 or 1
A

String Example
"C1-R1-C0-C0-A-R0-R1-R1-A-C1"

Smth like this /[CRA]\d-/gi only for each with separetor

OR better use split and map methods?

Comment: What is the problem here? Extract them all? Does `s.split('-')` return what you need? If yes, why not use `split`?

Comment: Better to use `split()` because there's no `-` at the end.

Comment: The simple answer is to match all that are `\b(?:[CR][01]|A)\b` is all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a regular expression, something like this should work:

```js
/^([CR][01]|A)(-([CR][01]|A))*$/
```

Essentially, we match a valid "parameter" as well as any number of "-parameter" after it. In context:

```js
const string1 = 'C1-R1-C0-C0-A-R0-R1-R1-A-C1';
const string2 = 'invalid';

const testString = (string) => {
  return /^([CR][01]|A)(-([CR][01]|A))*$/.test(string);
};

console.log(testString(string1));
console.log(testString(string2));
```

**Output:**

```js
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split and then filter with the regexp.

```js
let string = "C1-R1-C0-C0-A-R0-R1-R1-A-C1";
let result = string.split('-').filter(el => /^([CR][01]|A)$/.test(el));
console.log(result);
```